# What does ecxactly http do?

Tags: http, server, protocols

I understand that HTTP is a protocol that allows information to be transferred between a client and a server. At the moment, this protocol is used everywhere: when we're opening needed web page, downloading music, videos, applications...

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview#:%7E:text=HTTP%20is%20a,scripts%2C%20and%20more.)

> HTTP is a protocol for fetching resources such as HTML documents. It is the foundation of any data exchange on the Web and it is a client-server protocol, which means requests are initiated by the recipient, usually the Web browser. A complete document is reconstructed from the different sub-documents fetched, for instance, text, layout description, images, videos, scripts, and more.

But it's not entirely clear to me what exactly HTTP does during this information transfer. If, as I read, a protocol is essentially a set of rules, then does it mean that HTTP just setting up rules for passing information between server and client? If so, what are these rules and what are they for?

Answer (score 0):

Hypertext Transfer Protocol is a communications protocol. It is used to send and receive webpages and files on the internet. It is now coordinated by the W3C. HTTP version 1.1 is the most common used.

HTTP works by using a user agent to connect to a server. The user agent could be a web browser or spider. The server must be located using a URL or URI. This always contains http:// at the start. It normally connects to port 80 on a computer.

A more secure version of HTTP is called HTTPS (Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure). This contains https:// at the beginning of the URL. It encrypts all the information that is sent and received. This can stop malicious users such as hackers from stealing the information and is often used on payment websites. HTTPS uses port 443 for communication instead of port 80.